# Why am I getting an InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, winforms, invalidoperationexception

```
foreach (var shotItem in Invadershots)// it points to me to there and doesnt allow me to loop.."{"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."}"
{
  shotItem.Move();// it happens when this simple method called (which actually checks some bool..if the shot was out of the winform).
  if (shotItem.removeShot)
  {
        Invadershots.Remove(shotItem);
  }
}
```

Could it be because i change the List items simultaneously?
How can i prevent that error from occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot alter a collection whilst enumerating across it. Create a clone of the collection and alter that.

Comment: oooh okay, i see..damn.. i didnt know hat

Answer (score 5):

This is because you trying modify collection `Invadershots`

```
Invadershots.Remove(shotItem);
```

This is not allowed within foreach, use for instead..

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that deleting an element into a List, that you'r reading in a foreach will crash, surely, try to make a copy to remove with that while you're in the foreach, or make a for iteration and control de number of elements correctly and the out condition.

See you